# Searching Lucene.Net for Dates query

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene, lucene.net

I am building a Lucene index (using Lucent.Net  Version.LUCENE_30) and I am trying to search for a record based on a date.  I create the index like this:

```
if (sampleData.Start_Date != null)
  doc.Add(new Field("Start_Date", DateTools.DateToString(sampleData.Start_Date ?? DateTime.Now, DateTools.Resolution.SECOND), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

I then have a query like this:

```
LuceneData = LuceneSearch.search_query("(Start_Date : [20220601 TO 20220601])");
```

This query returns no records (though I know records exist with this value).  In this example, I just want to return all records with a Start_Date of 2022-06-01.  Am I indexing dates incorrectly or constructing the query string wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For others who may need this:  When I mapped my object to the Document, I had to recast the string back to a date, like this:

```
 Start_Date = DateTools.StringToDate(doc.Get("Start_Date"))
```

Once I did that, it worked.